# Pygame hitbox collision problems

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm making a 2D platformer game using Pygame, and I have made a code to detect if my character is on the floor or not. Below are the codes for the falling and the collision detection.

This is the collision code (In the Hitbox class):

```
def is_on_floor(self):
check_y = self.rect.y + self.rect.height
parent_y = self.rect.y - self.y_offset
collided = False
block_x, block_y,block_width,block_height = 0,0,0,0
points = [[self.rect.x, self.rect.y],
          [self.rect.x + self.rect.width, self.rect.y],
          [self.rect.x, self.rect.y + self.rect.height],
          [self.rect.x + self.rect.width, self.rect.y + self.rect.y]]
for obj in world:
    for point in points:
        if obj.hitbox.rect.x <= point[0] <= obj.hitbox.rect.x + obj.hitbox.rect.width and\
           obj.hitbox.rect.y <= point[1] <= obj.hitbox.rect.y + obj.hitbox.rect.height and\
           collided == False:
            block_x = obj.hitbox.rect.x
            block_y = obj.hitbox.rect.y
            block_width = obj.hitbox.rect.width
            block_height = obj.hitbox.rect.height
            collided = True
            break
    if collided:
        self.rect.y = block_y - self.rect.height
        parent_y = self.rect.y - self.y_offset
return parent_y, collided
```

And this is the falling code (In the Player class):

```
def fall (self):
    self.y_speed += 0.4
    self.y_pos += self.y_speed
    self.hitbox.update(self.x_pos,self.y_pos)
    floor_check, collided = self.hitbox.is_on_floor()
    if collided:
        self.y_pos = floor_check
        self.can_jump = True
        self.y_speed = 0
```

The problem is that my character just falls through the floor. But, the character *does* stand on a raised block that I added to the level for testing purposes. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

EDIT:
For adding new blocks, I am creating a copy of the block object. I tried this:

```
obj = copy.copy(self)
obj.hitbox = copy.copy(self.hitbox)
world.append(obj)
```

But it seems that when I update the block (So that the hitbox moves to it's position), it updates **one** hitbox that appears to be shared between the block objects. What I don't understand is that I used `copy.copy(self.hitbox)` to copy the hitbox, but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: you can use `rect.bottom` instead of `rect.y + rect.height` and `rect.right` instead of `rect.x + rect.width`

Comment: pygame has function to check collision between two rect - `rect.colliderect(other_rect)` and between rect and point `rect.collidepoint(other_rect.topleft)` . `rect` has property `topleft`, `topright`, etc.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20183823/1832058

Comment: use `print()` to see values when you checking collision - it can help to find problem.

Comment: see [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/) and [examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=en#section_38) (ie. platform_jumer.py in "Platformer examples") - they use `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` and `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`

Comment: Do I have to change anything else in my code if I change it to use `pygame.sprite.Sprite()`? I can give you the `__init__` and any other code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my own problem :P It seems the problem was *actually* in the way I made the hitboxes. To set it up, i input x, y, width, height as if it was a rect, but my hitbox class actually needed width, height, x_offset, y_offset. This means that I accidentally made hitboxes somehow had 0 width, 0 height, and were offset a lot, which was causing the wierd effects.