# How check if specific sites of a rect collide in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision

I want to ask if it's possible to check if two sites of two rect collide. For example if my player.rect.bottom site collides with my enemy.rect.top site.
I hope you know what I mean. Thanks :)

Comment: How about this one: http://pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html

Comment: you can check if single point collides with rect instead of checking if one point collides with other point - `player.rect.collidepoint(enemy.rect.bottom)` More: [Pygame: Collision by Sides of Sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180594/pygame-collision-by-sides-of-sprite)